# Fails to load remote files from web, but not CLI

Tags: php, http, apache, httpd.conf

I can load a remote file (http) from the php CLI:

```
php > print_r(getimagesize("http://www.google.ca/intl/en_ca/images/logo.gif"));
Array
(
    [0] => 276
    [1] => 110
        [2] => 1
    [3] => width="276" height="110"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/gif
)
```

However, the exact same code from a web script gives me:

```
[Thu Sep 03 21:47:53 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  getimagesize() [<a ref='function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/html/Whatsize/index.php on line 30
[Thu Sep 03 21:47:53 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(http://www.google.ca/intl/en_ca/images/logo.gif) [<a href='function.getimagesize'>function.getimagesize</a>]: failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/html/Whatsize/index.php on line 30
```

Do I have to change something in httpd.conf to allow remote file access?

Comment: could be a permission issue since the web user has limited access than running a script from the command line

Comment: raspi: It's on the same computer, what could be causing it? 

Phill Pafford: That's what the question's asking, what permission do I need to change

Comment: Are you using suhosin or SELinux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've (temporarily) at least solved the problem by restarting httpd. This seems to be a bug that's been floating around for a while.

http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/98/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-in-php-script/

If anyone has a more permanent solution, please reply. My web host does not seem to have this problem, so it's a good enough solution for me to test with.